# How to mask potential macro variables as part of a filename URL string

Tags: sas

I have written the following filename statement as part of a program to dynamically pull down stock quotes in iterative steps. This now works fine, except for three warning messages I am getting in the log:

1) &s= is not resolved
2) &f= is not resolved
3) Warnings: String is more than 252 characters long, you may have unbalanced quotations

filename loader url "http://finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=&svar1.+&svar2.+&svar3.+&svar4.+&svar5.+&svar6.+&svar7.+&svar8.+&svar9.+&svar10.+
&svar11.+&svar12.+&svar13.+&svar14.+&svar15.+&svar16.+&svar17.+&svar18.+&svar19.+&svar20.+
&svar21.+&svar22.+&svar23.+&svar24.+&svar25.+&svar26.+&svar27.+&svar28.+&svar29.+&svar30.+
&svar31.+&svar32.+&svar33.+&svar34.+&svar35.+&svar36.+&svar37.+&svar38.+&svar39.+&svar40.+
&svar41.+&svar42.+&svar43.+&svar44.+&svar45.+&svar46.+&svar47.+&svar48.+&svar49.+&svar50.+
&svar51.+&svar52.+&svar53.+&svar54.+&svar55.+&svar56.+&svar57.+&svar58.+&svar59.+&svar60.+
&svar61.+&svar62.+&svar63.+&svar64.+&svar65.+&svar66.+&svar67.+&svar68.+&svar69.+&svar70.+
&svar71.+&svar72.+&svar73.+&svar74.+&svar75.+&svar76.+&svar77.+&svar78.+&svar79.+&svar80.+
&svar81.+&svar82.+&svar83.+&svar84.+&svar85.+&svar86.+&svar87.+&svar88.+&svar89.+&svar90.+
&svar91.+&svar92.+&svar93.+&svar94.+&svar95.+&svar96.+&svar97.+&svar98.+&svar99.+&svar100.+
&svar101.+&svar102.+&svar103.+&svar104.+&svar105.+&svar106.+&svar107.+&svar108.+&svar109.+&svar110.+
&svar111.+&svar112.+&svar113.+&svar114.+&svar115.+&svar116.+&svar117.+&svar118.+&svar119.+&svar120.+
&svar121.+&svar122.+&svar123.+&svar124.+&svar125.+&svar126.+&svar127.+&svar128.+&svar129.+&svar130.+
&svar131.+&svar132.+&svar133.+&svar134.+&svar135.+&svar136.+&svar137.+&svar138.+&svar139.+&svar140.+
&svar141.+&svar142.+&svar143.+&svar144.+&svar145.+&svar146.+&svar147.+&svar148.+&svar149.+&svar150.+
&svar151.+&svar152.+&svar153.+&svar154.+&svar155.+&svar156.+&svar157.+&svar158.+&svar159.+&svar160.+
&svar161.+&svar162.+&svar163.+&svar164.+&svar165.+&svar166.+&svar167.+&svar168.+&svar169.+&svar170.+
&svar171.+&svar172.+&svar173.+&svar174.+&svar175.+&svar176.+&svar177.+&svar178.+&svar179.+&svar180.+
&svar181.+&svar182.+&svar183.+&svar184.+&svar185.+&svar186.+&svar187.+&svar188.+&svar189.+&svar190.+
&svar191.+&svar192.+&svar193.+&svar194.+&svar195.+&svar196.+&svar197.+&svar198.+&svar199.+&svar200.
&f=&&fvar&a.";

Firstly, how can I mask the &s= &f= from the processor, but allow it still resolve the &svar macro variables? I have tried various attempts at using %superq and %nrbquote but not had much luck.

Also, is there a way to a mask the warning about the string being long other than using log errors to suppress all options? Ideally I don't want to do that as I would still like to see any new errors that may arise for whatever reason.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To turn off the warning about string being too long, use system option NOQUOTELENMAX.

To mask an & that you can see, try %NRSTR(), e.g. %NRSTR(&f).

Comment: Thanks for replying. I had already got as far as %NRSTR by the time you had replied, but NOQUOTELENMAX was a big help, so thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To "mask" the ampersand so it is not scanned by the macro processor, just use the %STR function.  I don't see any reference to an `&s` variable in the code you show, but I do see one from`&f`.  Change that last parameter to:

```
%str(&)f=&&fvar&a.
```

Also, to assist debugging things like this, I strongly suggest that you build the entire string into it's own macro variable (perhaps named url).  In other words:

```
%let url="http://finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?%str(&)s=//svars// %str(&)f=&&fvar&a.";
%put url=&url; 
filename loader url "&url";
```

I'm guessing that the `s=` was `&s=` in the code that had the error and I substituted your long parameter string with `//svars//` only to save formatting in this answer.

Using a "helper macro variable" like this should help during development.  The `%put` just echos the string during testing and would not be part of the final macro.